# Sharepoint ODATA API & how to authenticate using service account

Tags: sharepoint, authentication, odata

I am calling the SharePoint 2010 REST/ODATA api and by default the data context uses DefaultCredentials, which is really the logged-in user of my Asp.Net application. If I don't attach DefaultCredentials to the context, then I just get 401 Unauthorized.

I was wondering how to call SharePoint API while using the Application Pool credentials? I am trying to follow the trusted systems security approach. Otherwise the SharePoint site needs to grant ODATA access and certain lists need be writable by basically everyone (gak!).

For example, with a SQL connection, I would just set "Integrated Security=true" to use the application pool credentials.

Answer (score 0):

Am I right that you are running an ASP.NET application on *other* than the SharePoint server? (Outside of the farm; just a machine with IIS and ASP.NET.) If your ASP.NET application pool runs under *the same user* as your SharePoint web application you can temporarily impersonate the code of you handler or page to the application pool user and use the [default network credentials](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.credentialcache.defaultnetworkcredentials.aspx):

```
using (HostingEnvironment.Impersonate()) {
    ICredentials credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
    // ... use the credentials
}
```

If you know credentials (name and password) of the application pool user from some configuration you can make the HTTP request using them directly:

```
ICredentials credentials = new NetworkCredential("user_name", "password");
// ... use the credentials
```

--- Ferda